# How do I map an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I can't figure this out and I've been at it for hours, so let's say I have an array of JSON. I want to map out the data into a new array.But I am stuck, could someone explain how to use map properly with an array of Json objects, thanks.

```
var results = [{
    "userid": 1213,
    "name": "jake",
    "id": 3242,
    "state": "ny"
}, {
    "userid": 1203,
    "name": "phil",
    "id": 3142,
    "state": "ny"
}, {
    "userid": 1013,
    "name": "kate",
    "id": 3241,
    "state": "js"
}];

$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    data: results,
    success:function(data){
    $.map(data.results, (dat, item) {
        var array = new Array();
        var groups;
        groups = array;
        groups.a = dat.userid;
        groups.b = dat.name;
        groups.c = dat.state;
        array.push(groups);
   } })
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `map` ?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Why do you want to "map"? The code you show seems to be the identity.

Comment: You're pushing the array into itself: `array` and `groups` reference the same array object.

Comment: There's so much wrong with your code, that I have no clue what you're trying to do. Please extend your question and elaborate what your input value is, and what your desired output should be. Also, why is there an ajax call? Should the transformed array be the calls data or should the calls response be transformed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forget *return* mapped obj.

```js
var results = [{
  "userid": 1213,
  "name": "jake",
  "id": 3242,
  "state": "ny"
}, {
  "userid": 1203,
  "name": "phil",
  "id": 3142,
  "state": "ny"
}, {
  "userid": 1013,
  "name": "kate",
  "id": 3241,
  "state": "js"
}];


console.log($.map(results, function(dat, item) {
  var groups = {};
  groups.a = dat.userid;
  groups.b = dat.name;
  groups.c = dat.state;
  return groups;
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am not supposed to return the object, I am supposed to push it into an array

Comment: @Newbieprogrammer, you can see in log, that map function return _array_. If this not what you want, can you provide expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Map your array before calling $.ajax();

```
results = results.map(function(item) {
  return {
    a: item.userid,
    b: item.name,
    c: item.state;
  };
});

//DO your thing
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    data: results
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you need to put your mapping code inside an ajax callback. Then, you can use either jQuery `map` or javascript `map` or simple for loop to iterate through each item in the response array.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    data: results,
    success: function( data )
    {
      var groups = data.map(function(currentItem){
        var group = {};
        group.a = currentItem.userid;
        group.b = currentItem.name;
        group.c = currentItem.state;
        return group;
      });
      console.log( groups );
    }
});
```